# Mysql2::Error: Can't read dir - after reinstall of mysql from homebrew on OS X

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, homebrew, mysql2

My previous install of MySQL on OS X was done manually with the native package installer.

Someone was helping me with an issue I had with upgrading some gems, and in process they installed mysql from the homebrew tools.

Since that point, I'm unable to access any of my local databases from MySQLWorkbench or from my various rails apps, but logging in with mysql on CLI using the same credentials allows me to read and write to all tables as normal.

The error I'm receiving from rails when I try to load a page is:

`Mysql2::Error: Can't read dir of './r4/' (errno: 13): SHOW TABLES LIKE 'schema_migrations'`

Any ideas as to what I can do to fix that?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have two different copies of MySQL Server running?  From workbench and from the CLI, try something like `SELECT @@VERSION,@@HOSTNAME;` in both places -- if not the same, that's the problem -- but if they are the same, then try `SELECT UUID_SHORT();` -- you should get two consecutive values if you're talking to the same copy of MySQL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the issue - permissions had changed on the /usr/local/mysql/data folder, I had to run:

`cd /usr/local/mysql/data`

`sudo chown -R _mysql mysql*`

*** Note: Replace `mysql*` with the directory/directories causing the error. ***

Comment: Replace "mysql*" with the directory/directories causing the error.